# Traversing to <a> tag in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

Going bonkers here!  Please can someone tell me why I can't seem to apply a class 'greyout' to the a tag.  I'm in the checkbox (this) and variable 'mydropID' reads "drop_billet" perfectly.   But then my code doesn't seem to traverse properly to the a tag and I get error 'Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined'.  I know there's nothing wrong with the CSS.  Many thanks for any help.

```
<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_billet" />Billet</label>

<select id="drop_billet" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
  <option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsID" class="RHLabelClass" >Details...</a>
```

.

```
var mydropID = '#' + ($(this).parent().next().attr('id')); 
$(mydropID).next().attr('id').addClass("greyout");
```

Comment: It's the checkbox.  But 'this' isn't the problem as 'mydropID' works perfectly well.

Comment: `.next().attr('id')` returns a string as you should already know because that's how you get the content of `mydropID` which is also a string O.o

Comment: Oh, of course.  But now I'm confused - how do I apply the class to the a tag?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Add class to the `select` when the `checkbox` is checked?

Comment: `$(mydropID).next().addClass("greyout");` should do it

Comment: You should have another look at the way jQuery works and what the different methods return: `$('#' + ($(this).parent().next().attr('id')))` is the same as `$(this).parent().next()`

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complicated. Instead of taking the `id` of `next()` and then getting the element by its `id`, use the element directly: `...parent().next().next().addClass(…)`.

Comment: Everything has to be relative to the checkbox (this). That's why it's a little complex.  What exactly do you mean by using the element directly?

Comment: @Silverburch: Like Andreas said, taking the `id` of an element and then getting the element by id is redundant. `...parent().next()`is the same as `$(mydropID)`. @hungersoft's solution should work but it's simpler the way Andreas and myself propose.

Comment: Got it - being dumb this morning.  All works now.  Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`$(mydropID).next().attr('id')` will return the id of the `a` and not the `a#TradeProdsID` itself, so if you want to access the element use `$(mydropID).next()`.

See the working code below.

```js
var mydropID = '#drop_billet'; 
$(mydropID).next().addClass("greyout");
```

```css
.greyout{
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_billet" />Billet</label>

<select id="drop_billet" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
  <option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsID" class="RHLabelClass" >Details...</a>
```

Comment: As @Renardo said I actually need the following to access the element $(mydropID).next().next().addClass("greyout");

Comment: But I'd love someone to explain why it doesn't work with just one .next()

Comment: @Silverburch oh you do not need two `.next()`, just one will do as it is working in my code. Try running my code snipped and see it adds the class grey to the `a` which makes its background color grey.

Comment: Well, I know you're right, as 2 lots of .next() shouldn't make any sense.  I've even hard coded the '#drop_billet' into my code to try and get it to work.  But for some weird reason it only works with 2.  Baffled!

Comment: @Silverburch do you see `a` with greyed background in my answer above? To run code in my answer click on `Run Code Snippet`.

Comment: I know, I'm not arguing with you.  I agree with you!  Just can't get it to work in my code.

Comment: Actually, to be more specific, I see 'Details' with greyed background, not a.

Comment: @Silverburch Oh I thought you didnt find it working in my code.

Comment: @Silverburch yea what else do you expect to get a background color if not `Details...`

Comment: To hopefully put an end to the one vs. two `next()`: When you start from the checkbox (`tr_billet`) as in the original code sample, you need two. When you start from the select (`drop_billet`) as @void does in her/his answer, you need only one.

Comment: @Renardo I agree with you.